# Email is not sent from my website

Tags: javascript, php, html, html-email

My forms to send emails don't work for some reason :S. I dont know if the problem is in my code or in my server setup but here's my code :

HTML :

```
<form onclick="return false;">
        <input type='text' placeholder='Your number' id="tel2" /><br />
        <select id="type_demande">
          <option>I want to purchase a land</option>
          <option>I want to sell a land</option>
        </select>
       <div id='messageenvoie' style="display:none;">Your number has been sent</div>
       <input type="image" src="images/general/en-norplan_bt.png" alt="bouton soumission" id="demande_appel"/>
      </form>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {

  $('#demande_appel').click(function() {

    $.post( "php/mail.php", { type_msg: "demande_appel", tel: $('#tel2').val(), type_demande: $('#type_demande').val()  } ).done(function(){
      $('#messageenvoie').show();
    });
  });
 });
```

and PHP:

```
$to       = 'info@gmail.com';
$subject  = 'Vous avez recu un message legroupegorplan.com';

switch($_POST['type_msg']){
  case 'demande_appel':
    $message  = "
                <h1>Demande d'un appel</h1>
                <table border='1'>
                <tr>
                  <td><b>No. de t&eacute;l&eacute;phone</b></td>
                  <td>" . htmlentities ($_POST['tel']) . "</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><b>Type de demande</b></td>
                  <td>" . htmlentities($_POST['type_demande']) . "</td>
                </tr>
                </table>";
    break;
}

$headers  = 'From: admin@legroupenorplan.com' . "\r\n" .
            'Reply-To: admin@legroupenorplan.com' . "\r\n" .
            'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" .
            'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();


mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

So this is a part of my code and as u can see I use it for other forms. None of the forms work. But I get the function back from the JS that Shows a DIV.

Can anyone help me please !

Thx

Comment: Add an error handler to the Ajax call, look at the response in the developer console.

Comment: and how do I do that? :S

Comment: Read the documentation on [jQuery Post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)